# Search by arabic word in facebook usig facebook Graph API

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to develop an application to search in Facebook.
the problem is that when using Arabic word to search, i got incorrect results (not-Arabic posts)
I tried to encode the Arabic word before passing it to search URL using the following encoding (UTF-8, ISO-8859-6 and Windows-1256), the results change, but still incorrect.

the following is the JAVA code that i use:

```
public JSONObject search(String strSearchPhrase, String strType) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    strSearchPhrase = URLEncoder.encode(strSearchPhrase, "ISO-8859-6");

    URL searchURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" + strSearchPhrase + "&type=" + strType + "&access_token=" + strAccessToken);

    URLConnection urlCon = searchURL.openConnection();

    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));

    String strInputLine;

    String strOutput = "";

    while ((strInputLine = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
        strOutput = strOutput + strInputLine;
    }
    buffReader.close();
    Object objOutput = JSONValue.parse(strOutput);
    JSONObject jsonOutput = (JSONObject)objOutput;

    //return data;
    return jsonOutput;
}
```

It works fine with English but not with Arabic

Any help or idea will be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you would post the code you use in order to search.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, I've tried this:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=محمود‎&type=user&access_token=xxxx"
```

and it seems like it worked fine, all the results where in this form: "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u0648\u062f"

When I try this:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=bob&type=user&access_token=xxxx"
```

the results have regular english characters.

I'm thinking that maybe your encoding is what's wrong, maybe try:

```
URL searchURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=محمود‎&type=" + strType + "&access_token=" + strAccessToken);
```

That is hardcode an arabic string into the url, check if that works.

Comment: thank you for care but the results unfortunately are incorrect. you can open this profile, it's the first result https://www.facebook.com/100001552568248

Comment: First result for what? I don't understand arabic, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your search url searches about person named "محمود", but the results of this search don't include this name, which means that the search didn't work fine, thank you